# How to render pugjs on electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pugjs

I am trying to use pug on electron.

I have a question my second `.pug` file is not rendered correctly, it just output the pug code itself.

First I have this main pug file that was loaded by the main.js

```
doctype
html(lang='en')
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title HIMS
  body
    div(id="app")
    script.
      require('./index.js')
```

then the index.js will just call the login.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('href', path.join(__dirname, 'style.css'));
document.head.appendChild(link);

const login = path.join(__dirname, 'login.pug');
fs.readFile(login, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    document.getElementById('app')
        .innerHTML = data;
});
```

but the `.innerHTML` will just output the pug code itself.

Please help how I can fix.
I will appreciate any advice or hint will come, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Pug is a language that can be used to write HTML more effectively. It is however not supported by any browser – including Chromium which is used by Electron – natively, so you either have to convert it to HTML using the [`pug` package](https://npm.im/pug) at runtime or compile your `.pug` files to `.html` files (using task runner plugins like [`gulp-pug`](https://npm.im/gulp-pug) for Gulp) and then load the generated `.html` files in your code.

The quickest solution to apply to your code is to use `pug.render` like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const pug = require('pug');

var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('href', path.join(__dirname, 'style.css'));
document.head.appendChild(link);

const login = path.join(__dirname, 'login.pug');
fs.readFile(login, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    const htmlData = pug.render(data)
    document.getElementById('app')
        .innerHTML = htmlData;
});
```